# Formatting a Formula in a String VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a script that needs to place a formula into a cell but I'm getting a 1004 error from the first part I am sure I formatted something wrong. I had difficulty with the " marks in the string but got those worked out so I'm figuring I'm missing something else. The cells are also unprotected.

```
Worksheets(CurSheet + 1).Range("D" & Y).Value = "=IF(D52=1,0,IF(C52=" & """Saturday""" & ",0,'" & CurSheet & "!C" & Y & "))"
```

This is the section that gives the error. If it is removed code works.

```
"=IF(D52=1,0,IF(C52="
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong with this part.

Comment: what is `CurSheet` declared as? What is the value assigned to it?

Comment: It looks like you're using `CurSheet` as an index number for your sheets, but then you're using it as a name in the formula and you're missing a `'` after you've used it in the formula.  For this code to work your workbook must contain at least 2 sheets, there must be a sheet called  `1`. `Y` and `CurSheet` must be set to _1_ and you need to add that missing `'` and change `.Value` to `.Formula` - but I guess that's not what you're after.  It will add the formula `=IF(D52=1,0,IF(C52="Saturday",0,'1'!C1))` to cell D1 in the sheet named `1`.

Comment: You could rewrite the code as `Y = 1: CurSheet = 1: Worksheets(CurSheet + 1).Range("D" & Y).Formula = "=IF(D52=1,0,IF(C52=" & """Saturday""" & ",0,'" & Worksheets(CurSheet).Name & "'!C" & Y & "))"`.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I suggest you post the formula line as an answer

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Your answer worked it was the (CurSheet).Name that errored out

Comment: I'll add as an answer - would have done it sooner, but only had my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using `CurSheet` as a sheet index number and as a sheet name.
The index number just returns the relative position of the sheet in the workbook while the name is what you see on the sheet tab (there's also the `CodeName` but I won't go into that here).

Although I don't fully understand what you're after this code will place a formula on the sheet identified with the sheet index number, so if CurSheet= 1(+1) it will place the formula on the second sheet.
The formula itself will reference the name of the sheet that is before the sheet that the formula appears on (so if the formula is on the second sheet, the formula will reference the first sheet).

```
Sub Test()

    Dim Y As Long
    Dim CurSheet As Long

    Y = 1
    CurSheet = 1

    Worksheets(CurSheet + 1).Range("D" & Y).Formula = _
        "=IF(D52=1,0,IF(C52=" & """Saturday""" & ",0,'" & Worksheets(CurSheet).Name & "'!C" & Y & "))"

End Sub
```

Hope I made that clear enough. :)

Comment: The sheet names are 1-31 and I was using the cursheet as an index of sorts in a loop that was adding formulas to sheets as they were being created but apparently I needed to add the .name to the code as that resolved it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare that you are inputting a formula, not a value:

Change:

```
Worksheets(CurSheet + 1).Range("D" & Y).Value
```

To:

```
Worksheets(CurSheet + 1).Range("D" & Y).Formula
```

Comment: I will try this out in a few. I didn’t realize you could specify the type

Comment: Well that didn't work but it informed me of the typing issue. Ill look more into it later

Comment: That is not the problem.  And in many instances, whether you use the `.Formula` or the `.Value` property won't make a difference.  Did you actually try running the OP's formula and get it to work without an error?